# How do I add multiple hyperlinks in a Label control in Windows Forms in Visual Basic 2008

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2008

In a label box, I want to list a couple of websites, email address along with some text. How do I go about it?

Potential uses-
As a Help > About dialog box where websites, email of the author can be listed.

Why? 
To make things as easy as possible for the user, and encourage visiting of the mentioned websites.

Simple text *will be* ignored, while standard blue color, underlined text with hand mouse-cursor will need no thinking on user's part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`LinkLabel.Links`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.linklabel.links) property gives you the ability to add multiple links.

To quote the page:

> A LinkLabel control can display any
>   number of links within the text of the
>   control.